# How can i undo this command

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, script

i recently found a post on a website and it said follow the solution and it will repair you cast in windows, but nothing happened after i did that, now i have question is it kind of hacking? How can i undo this?

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope LocalMachine -Force;
./sc config bthserv start= manual;./sc config DevQueryBroker start= manual;./sc config Audiosrv start= manual;
./sc config AudioEndpointBuilder start= manual;./sc config DeviceAssociationService start= manual;
./sc config DsmSvc start= manual;./sc config hidserv start= manual;./sc config BcastDVRUserService start= manual;
./sc config BluetoothUserService start= manual;./sc config CaptureService start= manual;
./sc config CDPUserSvc start= auto;./sc config DevicePickerUserSvc start= manual;
./sc config DevicesFlowUserSvc start= manual;./sc config MessagingService start= manual;
./sc config OneSyncSvc start= delayed-auto;./sc config PimIndexMaintenanceSvc start= manual;
./sc config PrintWorkflowUserSvc start= manual;./sc config UnistoreSvc start= manual;
./sc config UserDataSvc start= manual;./sc config WpnUserService start= manual;
./net start EventLog;./net start UsoSvc;./net start wuauserv;./net start AppXSvc;./net start BITS;./net start BFE;./net start MpsSvc;
./net start AppReadiness;./net start DcpSvc;./net start DevQueryBroker;./net start lfsvc;./net start NgcSvc;./net start NcbService;
./net start ScDeviceEnum;./net start SystemEventsBroker;./net start TimeBrokerSvc;./net start UserDataSvc;./net start UnistoreSvc;./net start ProfSvc;
Get-NetAdapterBinding | Enable-NetAdapterBinding -componentid "ms_rspndr";Get-NetAdapterBinding | Enable-NetAdapterBinding -componentid "ms_lltdio";
DISM /Online /Remove-Capability /CapabilityName:App.WirelessDisplay.Connect~~~~0.0.1.0;
DISM /Online /Add-Capability /CapabilityName:App.WirelessDisplay.Connect~~~~0.0.1.0;
```

I gave it from this site:
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/report-an-issue/windows-11-win-k-cast-no-longer-shows-all-bluetooth-devices/m-p/2923989/highlight/true#M4275

Answer (score 1):

This script does a lot of unnecessary stuff, but especially suppresses the
execution policy guards on PowerShell scripts, and also changes the
starting condition of many system services to "manual"
(so they don't start with boot).

This is not extremely harmful, but such widespread changes are
not really helpful.

If you have enabled System Restore, I would suggest to rollback to before
this was done. There are too many changes to undo one by one.

For more information on System Restore see
[How to Create a Restore Point and Roll-back to a Previous Restore Point](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/create-restore-protection-point-rollback-windows/).